# How can I use imagemagick attributes in the draw rectangle command?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to draw a rectangle across the full width of an image with `convert` [1]. I am trying to use [ImageMagick Attributes](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) to accomplish this.

The command I use is this:

```
convert ImageFile -fill black -stroke black -draw "rectangle 0,0 %[w],42" ImageFileNew
```

The Output I get is:

```
convert: NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition `rectangle' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3271.
```

With debug:

```
convert ImageFile -fill black -stroke black -draw "rectangle 0,0 %[w],42" ImageFileNew
```

I get:

```
2016-07-27T14:55:37+02:00 0:00.047 0.047u 7.0.2 Draw CONVERT[6660]: draw.c/DrawImage/1755/Draw
  begin draw-image
2016-07-27T14:55:37+02:00 0:00.047 0.047u 7.0.2 Draw CONVERT[6660]: draw.c/DrawImage/3207/Draw
  rectangle 0,0
2016-07-27T14:55:37+02:00 0:00.047 0.047u 7.0.2 Draw CONVERT[6660]: draw.c/DrawImage/3258/Draw
  end draw-image
CONVERT: NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition `rectangle' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3271.
```

I do not want to use a temporary file and I want to use this eventually after a trim repage. I would also like to replace the '42' with a formula if it is possible to use attributes in this command.

I guess the question is if this is supported( and if not then why the H not)?

[1] Version: ImageMagick 7.0.2-5 Q16 x64 2016-07-22 http://www.imagemagick.org

Answer (score 2):

> I guess the question is if this is supported( and if not then why the H not)?

It should be supported, but I would suggest using the `fx:` protocol to calculate the values.

```
convert rose: -fill red \
       -draw 'rectangle 0 0 %[fx:w] %[fx:h]' \
       out_fill.png
```

[image: out_fill]

I would guess you're seeing `NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition` as your starting to draw outside of the range of the [authentic pixels](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#authentic-pixels). Remember that column / row index start at `0`, and got to `nth - 1`.

```
convert rose: -fill red -stroke black -strokewidth 2 \
              -draw 'rectangle 0 0 %[fx:w-1] %[fx:h-1]' \
              out_stroke.png
```

[image: out_stroke]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately it does not work for me. I run convert from a cmd script. `convert` does not seem to accept any %[] attributes in the draw rectangle command. I used `-draw "rectangle 0,0 %%[w-1],42"` to get the least amount of errors, NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition appears every time I try to use attributes.

Comment: The `-draw` command does not accept %[fx...] values in the released (6.9.x) version of IM. It might in 7, but that isn't what most people have yet.

Comment: 2 years later, it seems this is still not working? I've tried with 7.0.8-11 and 7.0.8-14 and had no luck.

Comment: Ok, so as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642343/drawing-centered-rectangle-with-imagemagick/53642605#53642605, you should use `magick` and not `convert`