# Drawing centered rectangle with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Using the CLI, I'd like to add a black rectangle to an image that is 1) centered and 2) X pixels from every edge.

Basically, I almost want the opposite of `-border` (instead of adding a border of a certain color, I'd like to keep X pixels of my image as border, then paint everything else inside black. Also, image size should not change).

Something that I expected to work but didn't was:

```
convert myImage.jpg -fill black -draw "rectangle 10,10 %[fx:w-20],%[fx:h-20]" outImage.jpg
```

...for a "border" of 10 pixels. It looks like `-draw` doesn't accept FX operators or attributes, although I found somewhere (like in [How can I use imagemagick attributes in the draw rectangle command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614215/how-can-i-use-imagemagick-attributes-in-the-draw-rectangle-command)) that it should in IM 7.x (which is what I'm using).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ImageMagick 7, you should use magick and not convert. Using convert will make calls to ImageMagick 6 which does not support the fx in-line operations. In ImageMagick 7, do it this way for a 10 pixel border of image about the black rectangle:

Input:

[image]

```
magick lena.jpg -fill black -draw "rectangle 10,10 %[fx:w-11],%[fx:h-11]" result.jpg
```

[image]

Note that one should use 11 rather than 10, since the last pixel in the image is w-1,h-1. Numbering starts at 0. So I have corrected my original answer above.

Comment: Oh my, so the only real problem I had was using the wrong command (and I made a mistake with `20` versus `10`, but that was trivial to solve). Thank you!

Comment: For differences between ImageMagick 6 and 7, see https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli

Comment: Actually, the `fx` commands should be `%[fx:w-11]` for example, otherwise you'll chop a pixel, but anyway, thanks again!

Comment: That is true. I was going to correct that in my post, but I did not think it was that significant and issue. But glad that you figured it out.

Comment: I corrected it in my post for accuracy of the reply.